# serialize ajax post send old input values

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, serialization

I have a form with input fields and a button. When I click the button the form is serialized and the data is sent to a PHP file to be stored in the database.

I use `$("form.step1").serialize();` and when I `alert()` the data I get the correct values, but the AJAX post is sending the old values. When I send the input field data one by one, the form works fine:

```
$('button#nxt').on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var formdata = $("form.step1").serialize();
    alert(formdata);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/app/secure/includes/process_create_account.php",
        //data: { step: "1", user_name: ""+$('input[name="user_name"]').val()+"", user_company: "test" },
        data: formdata,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status) {
            alert("Sorry, there was a problem!");
        },
        complete: function (xhr, status) {}
    });
});
```

Why does `$("form.step1").serialize();` not work in my case?

Comment: may be your values are getting overwritten.
add this code at the top `echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);die;` in process_create_account.php and then hit your ajax

Comment: Replicate your issue e.g on jsFiddle because the behaviour you are describing isn't the expected one. Anyway, you should use the FORM submit handler, a FORM can be submitted in other ways than clicking a submit button and so your code would fail

Comment: Try adding cache: false to the ajax call.

Comment: @peedeeaay A POST request isn't cached by default (except on old IE if previously same request using GET was done but...).

Comment: This is my jsfiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/tkg3oees/ I can't post the php file there, but that's like: if(isset($_POST['step'])){
 if($_POST['step']==1){
 print_r($_POST); etc

Comment: Can't replicate with the code in your fiddle. Always gives me the new values eg.

`success: function (data) {  $( "#results" ).text( data ); }, `

What browser are you testing with?

Comment: Testing with Chrome and FF. For me the same, the new values in js and the old ones in php output...

Comment: Is it possible that the alert is coming before the php output is updated (as that's the order of execution) and causing confusion ? Move the alert inside the 'complete' stage ?

Comment: That's what I did before.. Then I get the same, the formdata gives the new values...

Comment: When I 'hardcode' the value in the script, it is send to the php file and the db is updated. So the post serialize can't use the new values, that's the big issue

Comment: Are you using some form of compression or performance boost on the server, eg. mod_gzip, edge caching?

Comment: Not that I know. The only thing I didn't tell you was that I load the page where the form is dynamicly with .load()

Comment: Oh! .load() is a GET request, and that caches. Add a timestamp to the url like so.

`$('#element').load('form.php?t='+new Date().getTime());`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this doesn't work.